# engineyard-local and Development workflow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, vagrant, engineyard

I'm moving my rails app from Dreamhost to EngineYard, then i'm testing the engineyard-local tool..

So, i'm really confused about, there's my questions:

- i'll develop inside the virtual machine? using `ey-local ssh` command;
- its necessary to use RVM?
- EngineYard Local is about "Devops Thing"   ?

anyone can explain his own workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Engine Yard Local is meant as an environment to develop and test your applications that will be deployed to Engine Yard Cloud. It also provides an easy way to test any custom Chef recipes that you may have written.

You can either develop entirely in the virtual machine or outside just use it for testing purposes. One of the biggest benefits of using Engine Yard Local is that development team members will all have the same environment.

If using Engine Yard Local for development, you shouldn't need to use the more advanced features of RVM (gemsets, etc.) and should just be able to start up the box and begin working. Developing outside of it in a team setting would be more customized based on your team's requirements.

DevOps is pretty much a buzz word and really is meant as a collaboration between development and operations teams. There's a lot of info available on the internet about DevOps.

In terms of workflow, typically I will develop the application locally like normal and then fire up the Engine Yard Local box before deploying to Engine Yard Cloud. But as discussed previously, you could actually develop entirely in the virtual machine.

Does this answer your questions?

--
Evan

Comment: I'm inside the Virtual Machine but i couldn't start the app in development env.

Comment: Nando, when the VM is running, you should be able to access it at localhost. The address should be in the Vagrantfile configuration.